# Need Help Configuring a MongoDB Monitoring Service in Icinga

Tags: macos, mongodb, monitoring, nagios, icinga

I am currently trying to track down an alert being dispatched by an icinga monitoring service for our mongodb server. Aprox. every 15 minutes a warning is being dispatched that looks like this:

> ***** Icinga  *****
>
> Notification Type: PROBLEM
>
> Service: check_mongodb_databases_service Host: myhost Address: myhost
>   State: WARNING
>
> Date/Time: 2016-07-13 10:02:20 -0400
>
> Additional Info: WARNING - Number of DBs: 20
>
> Comment: []

From the docs I have read so far it looks like icinga uses a 3rd party plug-in (https://github.com/mzupan/nagios-plugin-mongodb) to handle mongodb monitoring. Checking the docs far the plugin I found this command: https://github.com/mzupan/nagios-plugin-mongodb#check-size-of-a-database that seems to be responsible for checking the number of databases and throwing a wraning or error if the number passes a certain threshold.

What I can't for the life of me figure out is how to actually CHANGE that threshold. I'm sure there must be a config file somewhere, but nothing I have seen so far gives me any indication of where it might be. Please note that incinga2 (v2.0.0) is running on an OSX server if that makes any difference.